# adb Problems with Ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, adb

I am new to Linux and am attempting to set up my machine for Android development. I installed the SDK, and I set up the path to the "platform-tools" in my path by altering ~/.bashrc and adding the following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/home/user/sdk/platform-tools
```

When I type:

```
echo $PATH
```

into the command line, it spits back the directory to my sdk platform-tools.

Now, when I type:

```
adb devices
```

The command line says "adb command not found".

If anyone could help me out, it would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

~Nemisis7654

Comment: So what is the problem, exactly?

Comment: When I type "adb devices" into the command line, I get an error "adb command not found"

Comment: Which version of the SDK are you using?

Comment: did you check adb file's permissions?

Comment: I am using the most up to date version of the SDK (just downloaded and installed the day I asked this question). 

When I see what the permissions are, I have "rwxrwxrwx" as my permissions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you got the first step down, now you just need to add the udev values for your particular device.  See step 3 [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html#setting-up).  If you are using an emulator rather than a device adb should work fine without this step with what you have.  You have mentioned what you have done but not what the problem is so I assume this is the issue you are having.  What happens when you type `adb` into the terminal?

Comment: have you verified that you actually have adb downloaded yet?  can you `cd` to the platform-tools folder and then see if `./adb` does anything for you?

Comment: Yes. It brings up a list of all the commands that adb has. The starting sentence is: "Android Debug Bridge version 1.0.26"

Comment: double check there isn't a typo in your $PATH that has to be the problem.

Answer (score 5):

The solution that worked for me was found here (Ubuntu 11.10 x64)

http://kenno.wordpress.com/2011/10/27/ubuntu-11-10-32-bit-applications-do-not-run-64-bit/

and basically even though I had the tools installed I just needed to do a reinstall of the libc6-i386 and it finally found adb.

Comment: Might be good to note that this resolves the 'adb: file or directory not found' error and not the exact error in the initial question. Regardless, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: That link was close - I no longer get file not found but now it wants libstdc++.so.6.

Answer (score 3):

With the latest android SDK, adb should be under platform-tools.
Just put
export ANDROID=/usr/local/android/android-sdk-linux_x86
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID}/tools:${ANDROID}/platform-tools
and check the file permissions (for android or other binaries too).

Answer (score 2):

In older versions of the sdk, adb was located in the /sdk/tools directory.  You may need to create a symbolic link from platform-tools into that directory for adb:

```
ln -s /home/user/sdk/platform-tools/adb /home/user/sdk/tools/adb
```

Comment: The original poster already knew where the adb command is located.